# List of listing style in Latex

Tags: latex

I try to create a list of listing my code snippets in my latex document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{listings}
\renewcommand\lstlistingname{Code}
\renewcommand\lstlistlistingname{List of code snippets}

\title{Code Listing}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Code examples}

\begin{listing}
\begin{minted}
[
frame=lines,
framesep=2mm,
baselinestretch=1.2,
fontsize=\footnotesize,
linenos
]
{python}
import numpy as np

def incmatrix(genl1,genl2):
    m = len(genl1)
    n = len(genl2)
    M = None #to become the incidence matrix
    VT = np.zeros((n*m,1), int)  #dummy variable

    #compute the bitwise xor matrix
    M1 = bitxormatrix(genl1)
    M2 = np.triu(bitxormatrix(genl2),1) 

    for i in range(m-1):
        for j in range(i+1, m):
            [r,c] = np.where(M2 == M1[i,j])
            for k in range(len(r)):
                VT[(i)*n + r[k]] = 1;
                VT[(i)*n + c[k]] = 1;
                VT[(j)*n + r[k]] = 1;
                VT[(j)*n + c[k]] = 1;

                if M is None:
                    M = np.copy(VT)
                else:
                    M = np.concatenate((M, VT), 1)

                VT = np.zeros((n*m,1), int)

    return M
\end{minted}
\caption{Example of code}
\label{lst:code1}
\end{listing}

\clearpage

\lstlistoflistings

\end{document}
```

I don't know why my list look like this:

[image]

My caption under minted should change to Code 1: Example of code

**Caption Solution**

*replace:*
\renewcommand\lstlistingname{Code}

*to:*
\renewcommand{\listingscaption}{Code}

I read a lot of post but still not found the solution.. :(

I will be grateful for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, questions like this should be asked on [tex.stackexchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/).

As for the question itself, you're mixing two packages here. `minted` is separate from `listings`, so the commands from the latter work weirdly on the environments from the former (technically, they shouldn't work at all, but it's TeX we're talking about). According to `minted`'s [docs](http://ctan.mirrorcatalogs.com/macros/latex/contrib/minted/minted.pdf), that's what you should do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{minted} % don't need to import `listing` or `listings`

% custom labels, according to the docs 
\renewcommand\listingscaption{Code}
\renewcommand\listoflistingscaption{List of code snippets}

\title{Code Listing}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Code examples}

\begin{listing}[H] % creates a float
\begin{minted} % does the syntax highlighting
[
frame=lines,
framesep=2mm,
baselinestretch=1.2,
fontsize=\footnotesize,
linenos
]
{python}
your_code(...)
\end{minted}
\caption{Example of code}
\label{lst:code1}
\end{listing}

This is a reference to Code~\ref{lst:code1} to make it appear in the list of listings.

\clearpage

\listoflistings % NOT `lstlistoflistings`

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]